# How to get specific column data SQL for first row only in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to echo out some records in SQL database. This seems easy but I can't get it. So basically, I want to get all the columns a,b,c,d,e for the first row only and just a,b,c for the rest of the rows.

```
$query = $assdb->prepare("Select a, b, c, d, e from Table");
$query->execute();
$stmt = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($stmt as $row){
echo $row['a'] . $row['b']  . $row['c'];

//IF FIRST ROW, THEN ECHO $row['d'] and $row['e'], BUT IT DOES NOT WORK
if($row == 1){
    echo $row['d'] and $row['e']; 
  }

}//END FOREACH LOOP
```

HOW DO I CHECK FOR FIRST ROW? AND THEN ADD SPECIFIC DATA TO IT?

Comment: Also, if you want to get just one row of data returned, you can add: LIMIT 0, 1 to the end of your MYSQL query.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to get just one row

Answer (score 4):

Use simple flag `$is_first`:

```
$is_first = true;
foreach ($stmt as $row){
    echo $row['a'] . $row['b']  . $row['c'];

    //IF FIRST ROW, THEN ECHO $row['d'] and $row['e']
    if ($is_first) {
       echo $row['d'] . $row['e']; 
       $is_first = false;
    }
} //END FOREACH LOOP
```

Else you can use `foreach` like

```
foreach ($stmt as $key => $row) {
    echo $row['a'] . $row['b']  . $row['c'];
    if ($key == 0) {
        echo $row['d'] . $row['e']; 
    }
}
```

and if you `$stmt` is zero-indexed array check if `$key == 0`.