# Change data in the while loop while looping

Tags: php, while-loop

I am working in php and right now i am applying while loop to my code.
i am fetching  data from database. 
Now i have to apply that data on one Div in the page.

My problem is that "**div class="item active""** in the loop it take every time the active class. now i want to change that like after 1st loop process when second gone start i want to change that div to this "**div class="item""** .

I am little new at this looping process so i am not able to solve this. need help. Thanks.

```
<?php 

                $sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM eventdata WHERE id='$id'";

                $resultEvent = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlEvent);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($resultEvent) > 0) {

                while ($rowEvent = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvent)) {

                ?><div class="item active"> <img src="images/event/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                              <div class="carousel-caption wedding-area">
                                <h2><?php echo $rowEvent['eventTitle']; ?></h2>
                                <h4><?php echo $rowEvent['eventDate']; ?></h4>
                                <h4><?php echo $rowEvent['eventTime']; ?></h4>
                                <div class="details hidden-xs">
                                  <p><?php echo $rowEvent['eventDesc']; ?> </p>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Read More</a> </div>
                            </div><?php

                }

                }

                ?>
```

Comment: Use flag `is_first` and change it after first iteration. Thousands of such questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get specific column data SQL for first row only in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976456/how-to-get-specific-column-data-sql-for-first-row-only-in-php)

Comment: Not this time @u_mulder  are you blind ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter to check first iteration

```
$i = 1;// initialized counter
while ($rowEvent = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvent)) {
    if ($i == 1) {// check for first iteration
        ?><div class="item active"> <img src="images/event/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
    <?php } else { ?>

            <div class="item"> <img src="images/event/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                <?php
            }
            $i++;// increase counter

        ?>
```

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: Please up the question if it is.

Answer (score 0):

use pdo functions they are easier to use

http://php.net/manual/pl/pdostatement.fetchall.php

and always escape values in sql query!

```
<?php 


             $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventdata WHERE id=?);
             $sth->execute([$id]);
             foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $i => $rowEvent) {

            ?><div class="item  <?php if(1 === $i) echo 'active';?>"> <img src="images/event/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                          <div class="carousel-caption wedding-area">
                            <h2><?php echo $rowEvent['eventTitle']; ?></h2>
                            <h4><?php echo $rowEvent['eventDate']; ?></h4>
                            <h4><?php echo $rowEvent['eventTime']; ?></h4>
                            <div class="details hidden-xs">
                              <p><?php echo $rowEvent['eventDesc']; ?> </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Read More</a> </div>
                        </div><?php

            }


            ?>
```

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want only the first div of the loop has class "active"... 
then this code should work for you

Just set variable = "actìve" then at the end of the body loop set = "".

In each iteration print the variable in the class attribute of your div

```
$sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM eventdata WHERE id='$id'";

$resultEvent = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlEvent);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultEvent) > 0) {
    $classActive = "active";
    while ($rowEvent = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvent)) {
        ?>
            <div class="item <?php echo $classActive; ?>"> 
                <img src="images/event/1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption wedding-area">
                    <h2><?php echo $rowEvent['eventTitle']; ?></h2>
                    <h4><?php echo $rowEvent['eventDate']; ?></h4>
                    <h4><?php echo $rowEvent['eventTime']; ?></h4>
                    <div class="details hidden-xs">
                      <p><?php echo $rowEvent['eventDesc']; ?> </p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Read More</a> </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        $classActive = "";
    }

}
```